# My app works fine on localhost but throws error in production

Tags: reactjs, mern, internal-server-error

My MERN stack app works fine on localhost.But when tried to run on heroku, first page loads and when refreshed it shows "Internal Server Error 500".Does anyone know what could be the potential solution? I searched on google but couldn't find anything working.